# Errors in Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code doesn't work, anyone have any recommendations?

Perhaps I did something wrong? Anyone could check this code please? Is that because I used jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function showCart(next) {
    var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");
    var params = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.clientCart.elements.length; i++) {
        param = getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);
        if (param != "") params += param + "&";
    }
    if (next) params += "Next=1";
    ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);
    makePie();
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? This code on its own is not really enough for us to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an extra `}` at the bottom.

So

```
$(document).ready(function showCart(next) {
    var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");
    var params = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.clientCart.elements.length; i++) {
        param = getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);
        if (param != "") params += param + "&";
    }
    if (next) params += "Next=1";
    ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);
    makePie();
});
```

at least doesn't have any syntax issues.

Comment: the NFE is not a problem at all

Comment: @Esalilija when i take it out, i don't get any errors.  when i leave it in, I do

Comment: The error is from the braces, not from NFE. Run `$(document).ready(function showCart(next) {console.log(next);});` Naming function expression is perfectly legit, and much better practice than using `arguments.callee`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(next){
    var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");
    var params = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.clientCart.elements.length; i++) {
        param = getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);
        if (param != "") params += param + "&";
    }
    if (next) params += "Next=1";
    ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);
    makePie();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many closing braces:

```
$(document).ready(function showCart(next) {
    var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");
    var params = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.clientCart.elements.length; i++) {
        param = getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);
        if (param != "") params += param + "&";
    }
    if (next) params += "Next=1";
    ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);
    makePie();
}  // <-------------- that shouldn't be there
});
```

Also, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `next` in your function will always be `jQuery`, so why not remove it, and just reference jQuery as `jQuery` (or `$` if you're not in noconflict mode)

Also note that you can simplify

```
$(document).ready(function showCart(next) {
```

to:

```
$(function showCart(next) {
```

Or ditching the unnecessary `next` parameter, and function expression name

```
$(function () {
```

Comment: Also `next` doesn't make any sense, since it's always `jQuery`

Comment: The code is beyond help anyway (which is why I didn't make an answer lol) because it doesn't do what the OP thinks it does. `showCart` can only be called outside itself in older IE because of a bug. I think he wants to call it with some `next` param in some point of code. :P

Comment: "Or ditching the unnecessary `next`" - Hahahahahaha!